# lambda self in function

Tags: python, django

I was going through a github project to get the current request user in `django` projects and I saw this codes and I didn't understand use of lambda in this code. 
Somebody please explain this .

```
def _do_set_current_user(user_fun):
    setattr(_thread_locals, USER_ATTR_NAME, user_fun.__get__(user_fun, local))


class ThreadLocalUserMiddleware(object):

 ..........
 ................

  _do_set_current_user(lambda self: getattr(request, 'user', None))


def get_current_user():
    current_user = getattr(_thread_locals, USER_ATTR_NAME, None)
    if callable(current_user):
        return current_user()
    return current_user
```

here I couldn't understand what is the use of `user_fun.__get__(user_fun, local)` in this line 
`setattr(_thread_locals, USER_ATTR_NAME, user_fun.__get__(user_fun, local))`.
instead we can set the attr like this instead

```
setattr(_thread_locals, USER_ATTR_NAME, user)
```

here why its using lamda function why we cannot set the user object instead.
somebody please explain

Comment: @djangonaut could you please check this , i got it from your repo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but if you just want the current user of the request, it's `request.user` in view functions or `self.request.user` in class-based views.

You can check if the user is authenticated with `request.user.is_authenticated`.

This is set by the `AuthenticationMiddleware`.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#attributes-set-by-middleware

You can also access the user in a custom Middleware if yours is listed after `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`, also via `request.user`.

Comment: i want to access the request objects everywhere in my application . thats the reason im creating a seperate middleware for that.

Comment: Updated my answer - you can do that too.